# Distributional solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

How to solve the following differential equation on the space of distributions? 
$$
u'+tu=K(0,1),
$$
Here $K_{(0,1)}$ is the characteristic function of the closed interval between $0$ and $1$. I managed to find out that the problem is to find a $u$ such that the following integral equation is satisfied:

$$\int  u(t) (-exp(t^2/2)) (exp(-t^2/2) p(t) )'dt=\int K_{(0,1)}(t) p(t)dt$$

where $p$ ranges over infinitely differential functions of compact support, and integration is on the line.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE, Kindly refrain yourself from posting questions without any effort of your own, Kindly attach your own method or your trial to improve the question.

Comment: Hello, done as required.

Comment: Why do you want a distributional solution? You can easily compute a piecewise differentiable solution from the general solutions of $u'+tu=0$ and $u'+tu=1$.

Comment: That is true but this is an exercise. I should find the classical solutions of the homogenic problem, then find one particular solution on the space of distributions. These latter objects additively form the general solution of the problem.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to just write down the piecewise differentiable solution as @LutzL suggested and then check that it is a weak solution of the full problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and how do I know that there are no more solutions exclusively distributional?

Comment: Don't forget the solutions to the homogeneous equation.